# effect of <hr> tag on next sibling which is ul>li

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>technical documentation page</title>
    <style>
        ul:nth-child(2){
              float: left;
              position: fixed;
              width:auto;
        
    }
             nav>ul li{
             border: 1px solid gray;
             padding: 25px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav id="navbar">
        <header>
            <h1>SSAGUJARAT WEB-TECHNICAL EXPLANATION</h1>
        </header>
        <hr>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#LOGIN" class="nav-link">LOGIN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#MENUBAR" class="nav-link">MENUBAR</a></li>
            <li><a href="#MASIKPATRAK" class="nav-link">MASIKPATRAK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#PAGARBILL" class="nav-link">PAGARBILL</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SHORTCUTS" class="nav-link">SHORTCUTS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

I have navbar floated in left and positioned fixed with css but when I add hr tag bellow header, navbar and each li inside navbar taking full width with border, navbar is missing float left and also missing position fixed. why??

Comment: Add tag `<hr>` to your code, pls.

Comment: hr added. i am facing this issue when i add hr tag.

Comment: question. why do you use ` ul:nth-child(2)` ? and not just `ul` ?  This is causing the problem. Because by adding another element ( `<hr>` in your case but it could be anything, you would have the same result ) BEFORE the `ul` means that `ul` is not the 2nd child anymore of `<nav>` but the 3rd one. So i suggest you don't use `nth-child` pseudo-selector all together. or change it from 2 to 3. Also, another suggestion, don't use `float` for layout purposes. Use flexbox or css grid instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, `ul` will not have CSS anymore because you are targeting `ul:nth-child(2)` and after adding hr it should be `ul:nth-child(3)`

```css
 ul:nth-child(3){
     float: left;
     position: fixed;
     width:auto;
}
 nav>ul li{
     border: 1px solid gray;
     padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>technical documentation page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav id="navbar">
        <header>
            <h1>SSAGUJARAT WEB-TECHNICAL EXPLANATION</h1>
        </header>
        <hr>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#LOGIN" class="nav-link">LOGIN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#MENUBAR" class="nav-link">MENUBAR</a></li>
            <li><a href="#MASIKPATRAK" class="nav-link">MASIKPATRAK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#PAGARBILL" class="nav-link">PAGARBILL</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SHORTCUTS" class="nav-link">SHORTCUTS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

**Suggestion:**

I'm not aware of your full code but In your case, you don't have to use `nth-child` you can easily use `ul` or consider adding a `class` to your `ul` (which is better) then target it in your CSS, here is an example:

```css
 ul.nav-items {
     float: left;
     position: fixed;
     width:auto;
}
 nav>ul.nav-items li{
     border: 1px solid gray;
     padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>technical documentation page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav id="navbar">
        <header>
            <h1>SSAGUJARAT WEB-TECHNICAL EXPLANATION</h1>
        </header>
        <hr>
        <ul class="nav-items">
            <li><a href="#LOGIN" class="nav-link">LOGIN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#MENUBAR" class="nav-link">MENUBAR</a></li>
            <li><a href="#MASIKPATRAK" class="nav-link">MASIKPATRAK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#PAGARBILL" class="nav-link">PAGARBILL</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SHORTCUTS" class="nav-link">SHORTCUTS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```